# Change part of controltemplate in styled controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, styling, controltemplate

I have customized the ToggleButton control using a ControlTemplate like so:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="OptionBarButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Border Padding="18,12,18,12" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkBlue" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="True" />
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="SkyBlue" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#88000000" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition Property="IsChecked" Value="False" />
                                    <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#F0000000" />
                                </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource OptionBarButton}">
        <Image Source="../Assets/icons/action.png" Height="26" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" />
    </ToggleButton>

    <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource OptionBarButton}">
        <Image Source="../Assets/icons/action2.png" Height="26" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" />
    </ToggleButton>

</StackPanel>
```

This works fine, however I would now want to change some parts of the template in some of the styled controls, namely the IsChecked color states (SkyBlue/DarkBlue).

Is it possible to modify / pass these colors in/to the template when using it? I know I can use attached properties or/and subclass the ToggleButton class (adding dependency properties to it), but I was wondering if there isn't a more idiomatic way to solve this, perhaps only with xaml. Having to write custom code in C# seems a little bit overkill for such a simple use case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this without code, as far as I know, but if you really want to - you can utilize dynamic resources in certain way. Usually dynamic resources are used to change appearence of ALL instances of control at runtime. You reference dynamic resource from template, then change that resource and all controls reflect this change. This is probably not what you need in this case, because you want to change "some parts of the template in some of the styled controls". You can still do it like this:

```
<!-- default checked and over color -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TgCheckedAndOver" Color="DarkBlue" />
<!-- default checked color -->
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="TgChecked" Color="SkyBlue" />
<Style 
       TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Border Padding="18,12,18,12"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked"
                                       Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                       Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource TgCheckedAndOver}" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked"
                                       Value="True" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                       Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="{DynamicResource TgChecked}" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked"
                                       Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                       Value="False" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="#88000000" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsChecked"
                                       Value="False" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver"
                                       Value="True" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Background"
                                    Value="#F0000000" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

This is regular use of dynamic resource. Now when you want to change appearence just for particular control, you do this:

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Resources>
        <!-- override default resources -->
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TgChecked" Color="Yellow" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TgCheckedAndOver"
                         Color="Green" />
    </ToggleButton.Resources>
    <Image Source="../Assets/icons/action.png" Height="26" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="Fant" />
</ToggleButton>
```

Because you place new resources with the same keys "closer" to the control - template will use them instead of default ones, and just this particular control will do that, not all of them.

Comment: Ah, this is great. I can definitely see this being useful in other scenarios as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, ControlTemplates are a all-or-nothing thing. If you want to change the colors you reference inside them, you have to switch templates. I suppose that having **references to resources** in the template is not an option for you.

I would create Dependency Properties for each of the variable colors in OptionBarButton.

Comment: Ok, I see. Is there any other technique than ControlTemplates that would be better suited for this situation?

Comment: I have just seen the DynamicResource solution. I really like it. Go that way!